# First Activity to Second Activity (Intent, Database and Adapter)

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-activity

I have a database and adapter for the first activity showing the name and description. There is a button on each list item which takes you to the second activity displaying a unique image related to that item.

I have included an Intent from the first activity to the second activity.

So on the second activity I would like to add the image related to the item clicked.

Question:

(a)Do I include the image in the same database for the first activity or do I need a separate database and adapter for the second activity?

(b)Also do I need to create a separate intent for each item in the first activity as each item has a separate image that it will link to via the button which will be displayed on the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your click  listener will be one and generic as same lite item view is inflated for all items of adapter.
   2.on click you need to pass the Uri string to second activity via intent and display the image Uri in second activity after receiving it from getIntent()  in oncreateview()  of second activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this in two parts.

- Part 1: the database: You should use the same table for the image as well. You can always talk to the same database and all the tables from any activity, so no need to have a separate database. So the name, description and image in the same activity.
- Part 2: The intent

If you are in a scenario where you have to add any action on click of an adapter item, always use a callback.
When you click on any item, this callback will tell you in the activity that which item in the adapter is clicked.
[This medium blog](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9) is a very good example to demonstrate this.

In this blog's code, there is a block in adapter where you pass the values from the activity. It is the constructor.

```
RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
}
```

If you had added some code, it would help, but I am sure you also have this constructor in your code, so add this listener along with the other data and see how it works out.

Thanks